# Summing 2 Statements Tableau

Tags: tableau-api, calculated-field

In Tableau, what are the rules when it comes to adding 2 statements if you cannot put everything in 1?  In the first part of the statement below, I am trying to pull all products besides 1 of them from a distributor, then in the part I am trying to pull all the units except from 2 of the distributors.  However, as you can guess, the cells are blank when I drag the pill over.

Is it best practice to just create 2 calculated fields and add THOSE together?

```
(IF [Distributor] = "NDC"
AND [Product] <> "PE Single Use"
THEN ['15] END)
+
(IF [Distributor] <> "NDC" 
AND [Distributor] <> "M&D"
THEN ['15] END)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are a few simple rules about calculations in Tableau (and generally in SQL also)

1. If you don't specify a value in some case, say by leaving off the else clause in an if statement, the expression evaluates to null in that case. That can be fine or a problem depending on what you want. Consider null to mean no-value, or not-applicable or missing-value depending on your situation.
2. Nulls propagate through other expressions. A null value + anything yields a null value. You can explicitly test for null if necessary, but it is often better to keep simple expressions that evaluate to null when any part is null.
3. Aggregation functions like SUM(), MIN(), AVG() etc silently ignore null values. So AVG(Salary) is really the average of all the rows that had a non-null value in the Salary field. You don't get any warning about this, it is understood. If you want to know how many rows have a non-null value for a field, you can use the COUNT() function to check.

In your expression above, the two IF conditions are never both true for the same record. So at least one of the two halves of your expression is null in each case, so the resulting entire expression is always null.

There are other rules to learn when using table calcs and LOD calcs, but these rules apply throughout.